# Not getting data due to difference in Timezone using java

Tags: java, sql, date, datetime

my course timezone is MST .I Have submitted assignment of course in 11:30 pm of `12/9/2014(MST)`.But am storing standard timezone in db as US/EASTERN.The differene between MST and  `US/EASTERN` is 3 hrs.so it is storing in `13/9/2014`.when i trying to get data on `12/09/14 (12:00:00 Am)`according to my system `date(IST)`...will be converted into MST and then `US/EASTERN`.I  am not getting the data....if i choose `13/9/14` then am getting data.

I am using this sql query

```
<#if selectedDate??>AND sas.SUBMITTED_DATE < (TO_DATE('${toDate?string("dd-MMM-yyyy")}', 'DD-MON-YYYY') + 1) </#if>
```

If i changed to like this, working fine..but will fail in some other scenario

```
<#if selectedDate??>AND sas.SUBMITTED_DATE < (TO_DATE('${selectedDate?string("dd-MMM-yyyy")}', 'DD-MON-YYYY') + 2) </#if>...
```

need to work in all scenarios

Comment: You need to store your data in UTC, then render it with the timezone required.

Comment: no.... need to store data in US/EASTERN ONLY....according to my course timezone ..need to get data

Comment: @user3318237 No, you *really* need to adjust your date-time values to UTC when storing, or have the database do it for you, as Burhan Khalid suggests. Please search StackOverflow to study. Start [here](http://stackoverflow.com/q/2532729/642706).

Comment: Also, when asking a database question, you must provide us with the *exact* data type of the column, what database, and the means of communication between your app and the database (JDBC?), if you want the most helpful answers.